# 'AllowOverride All' and .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, wamp, wampserver

I've setup a local website with wamp but I have some problem with url and htaccess.

I have the folder 'project' inside 'wamp/www'...I've setup a  virtualhost as 'project.local';

On the root of the project folder there is a .htaccess with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine  on
  RewriteBase    /lab
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that I can access http://project.local/some.php, but I need to access as http://project.local/lab/some.php

I've changed the AllowOverride rule at httpd.conf, but still can't fix.

What is wrong? thanks

Comment: AllowOverride has nothing to do with you using a subfolder. You need a folder in your docroot called lab and put `some.php` in there. No rewrite is needed for that.

Comment: Ok, but I don't need another htaccess on the docroot so I can access http:/project.local and this change to http:/project.local/lab ?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking or what you are trying to do. Please try rewriting you question, making it clear what you are trying to do and Why

Answer (score 2):

First, I would write your .htaccess like this (or something like it):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^lab/(.*)/?$ $1
```

Then, put your `AllowOverride All` line within the `<Directory /path/to/www>`, all of which are inside your `<VirtualHost>` tags. Like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/www/"
    ServerName project.local

  <Directory "/path/to/www/">
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

[This site](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708) has some good info about mod_rewrite.